# Postgresql query: schema does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I've a problem with my PostgreSQL query. I'm a beginner so maybe it's a dumb question:

I need to find the client that has been the most to the moon.
I tried to find the solution with a subquery but I cannot fix the errors.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT klantnr,count(reisnr) as aantal
FROM (SELECT reisnr,klantnr,objectnaam
        FROM Hemelobjecten H INNER JOIN bezoeken b
        USING(objectnaam)
        INNER JOIN deelnames D
        USING(reisnr)
WHERE H.objectnaam = 'Moon') as Query
    WHERE Query.objectnaam = 'Moon' 
    GROUP BY klantnr
    HAVING count(reisnr) = MAX(Query.count(reisnr))
```

This gives me the error:
ERROR:  schema "query" does not exist

*** *Error* *****

ERROR: schema "query" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000

How can I fix it?

The query:

```
SELECT klantnr,count(klantnr)
        FROM Hemelobjecten H INNER JOIN bezoeken b
        USING(objectnaam)
        INNER JOIN deelnames D
        USING(reisnr)
        WHERE H.objectnaam = 'Moon'
GROUP BY klantnr
```

Gives me:

```
125;1
122;1
124;3
121;4
123;3
126;1
```

I only need the row with the highest values in the right column.
Thats the reason why I use

Comment: `MAX(Query.count(reisnr))` is nonsense, the parser thinks that `Query` is a schema name.

Answer (score 1):

The `HAVING` clause is trying to do too much. You could write a subquery to determine the correct MAX value, but it might be considerably easier to do this:

```
ORDER BY count(reisnr) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you don't need the reisnr to count the number of trips to the moon. (every record found constitutes a different trip). The code below is a (rather bulky, but very readable) CTE to count the aggregate score of trips to the moon *per person* and compare them in the final query, avoiding the `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH dinges AS (
        SELECT distinct klantnr
                , count(*) as aantal
        FROM Hemelobjecten H 
        INNER JOIN bezoeken b USING(objectnaam)
        INNER JOIN deelnames D USING(reisnr)
        WHERE H.objectnaam = 'Moon'
        GROUP BY klantnr
        )
SELECT klantnr
FROM dinges a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dinges nx
        WHERE nx.aantal > a.aantal
        );
```

Comment: Can I solve it without "with", the teacher told me I can solve it only with a HAVING. I tryed a lot but now it gives me only those were aantal = 1 Here is the code I used: SELECT klantnr as K1, count(Q1.aantal) as K2
FROM (SELECT D.klantnr, count(D.reisnr) as aantal
 FROM deelnames D INNER JOIN reizen r
  USING(reisnr)
 INNER JOIN bezoeken b
  USING (reisnr)
 WHERE B.objectnaam = 'Maan'
 GROUP BY D.klantnr) as Q1
GROUP BY klantnr
HAVING count(aantal) = (SELECT MAX(Q1.aantal));

Comment: Since the Q1 refers to a subquery, I _think_ that would work, but maybe you dont need the SELECT on the RHS: `... HAVING count(aantal) = MAX(Q1.aantal)`. Why don't you try? (I would try if I had the table definitions, but I am too lazy to invent them for you) BTW: a WINDOW function could also be possible.